# Is there a way to not hardcode the Selenium Server Path in Nightwatch.json file?

Tags: nightwatch.js, selenium-server

This is my nightwatch.json file currently:

[nighwatch.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9pmd.png)

My question : Is there a way to reference the server_path .jar file as a means to avoid the hard coded value of selenium-server-standalone-2.51.0.jar? I am wondering because our company would like to have the selenium version update every time that our package.json file updates. Once the selenium version changes, our tests break because of this hard coded value. I have tried:

1)

```
"../node_modules/selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar///*.jar"
```

This failed with the error message of 'Unable to access jar file'.There is only one .jar file available to choose from.

2) Referencing our package.json file that contains the desired version of the selenium-server-standalone package through npm.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to set up Nightwatch myself, with the same requirement.

So here's what I did:

1) In the nightwatch.json, I leave out the file name:

```
...
"selenium" : {
  "start_process" : true,
  "server_path" : "node_modules/selenium-standalone/drivers/selenium-server/",
...
```

2) From here: http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#settings-file
you can see that you can use javascript to change the config. I'm getting the selenium server using the [selenium-standalone npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone).
In the `package.json` at `scripts.postinstall` I have:  `selenium-standalone install --basePath %cd%/node_modules/selenium-standalone/drivers`

Therefore I know where the drivers are installed, and can use the `node fs` package to find out the name of the currently installed selenium file:

```
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = (function(settings){
  var seleniumFileName =
  fs.readdirSync("node_modules/selenium-standalone/drivers/selenium-server/")[0];
  settings.selenium.server_path += seleniumFileName;
  return settings;
})(require("./nightwatch.json"));
```

Runs like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this method:

Your `nightwatch.json` selenium property should look like this:

```
...
"selenium": {
    "start_process": true,
    "server_path": "node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/selenium-server/",
    "log_path": "./reports",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 4444,
    "cli_args": {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver": ""
    }
  }
...
```

Your `nightwatch.conf.js` should look like this:

```
require('babel-core/register');
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = ((settings) => {
  var seleniumFileName =
  fs.readdirSync("node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/selenium-server/");
  settings.selenium.server_path += seleniumFileName;
  return settings;
})(require("./nightwatch.json"));
```